# Intel Rapid Storage Technology RAID - what can you schedule?

Tags: raid

I am about to get a new laptop and I am considering using the Intel firmware RAID to set up RAID-1.  I am researching what features it has.

I found the following screenshot of the Intel Rapid Storage Technology software showing the Preferences tab containing "System", "E-mail", and "Scheduler" sections.  Does anyone know what is in the Scheduler section?  I'd like to know exactly what tasks can be scheduled.

[image]

I also found the following screenshot of the Preferences tab and it doesn't have the "Scheduler" section.  Is that just an older version of the Intel RST software, or could there be certain system configurations that don't allow access to the Scheduler?  Also, why does this screenshot have a Performance tab (the first screenshot doesn't) and doesn't have a Create tab (the first screenshot does)?

[image]

I found the [Intel Rapid Storage Technology user guide](http://download.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/irst_user_guide.pdf), and there is no mention of scheduling in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for scheduling array verification checks for data inconsistencies, and optionally perform repairs.

More info from Intel on what these checks/repairs do:

> The RAID volume data verification process identifies any inconsistencies or bad data on a RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 5 or RAID 10 volume.
>
> The RAID volume data verification and repair process identifies and repairs any inconsistencies or bad data on a RAID 1, RAID 5 or RAID 10 volume.
>
> The following describes what occurs for each RAID level:

[image]

[Source](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-023081.htm)

You can schedule it to happen once, daily, weekly or monthly.

Screenshots of the Scheduler menu:

[image: RST Schedule screen]

[image: RST scheduling interval options]

Comment: Do you know the scheduling options - can you schedule it for a specific time each day, or specific days of the week?

Comment: @pacoverflow Added a bit more text, and some screen shots to my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  Does the verify feature slow down the system at all?

Comment: It does while the verification is happening, hence why they provide a way for you to schedule it. ;)

Comment: I have another question about the table that you posted - for RAID 1 it says "If the data on the mirror drive does not match the data on the source drive, the data on the mirror is overwritten with the data on the source."  What if the mirror data is correct and the source data is corrupted?